# Inconsistent Accessibility parameter type is less accessible than method? C#

Tags: c#, struct, accessibility

I am trying to reference two Global structs in my function

```
 HandleCSVData(strSortedStringArray,ref srRecord,ref srScores);
```

They are `global` by definition is in the `public partial class Form1 : Form` part of the code. `HandleCSVData` is called inside `public Form1()` and is declared below it as `public static void HandleCSVData(string[] arr, ref SRec sr, ref Scores s) {` But I am getting this error

```
Error   1   Inconsistent accessibility: parameter type 'ref SoldierApp.Form1.ScoreRec' is less accessible than method 'SoldierApp.Form1.HandleCSVData(string[], ref SoldierApp.Form1.SoldierRec, ref SoldierApp.Form1.ScoreRec)'    \Form1.cs   101
```

I've tried nearly everything. I'm not sure what the error means I am pretty new to C# hence all the questions in the past week on c#. Anyone give me any ideas as to what the error means and how I can fix this?

Answer (score 3):

The error is extremely clear, `SoldierApp.Form1.ScoreRec` is less accessible than your `public` function call.

Either make `ScoreRec` `public` or `HandleCSVData` `private`/`protected`.

Comment: That's odd I'm not really sure how that handles this? I changed it to private and it's working now. can you please clarify this?

Comment: Which part is confusing you? You can't expose a less visible type from a more visible method.

Comment: Ok so the Main is more visible or Form1 is more visible compared to the public function `HandleCSVData`